# Django admin process file after upload complete

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-admin

How do I process any operation on file after its upload is completed?

I need to copy uploaded file on remote server immedeatly after upload, get response from remote server and put it into database.

I have tried to do it in save_model of ModelAdmin like this:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.answer = remote_upload(obj.file.path)
        obj.save()
```

remote_upload is self-written function, it successfully uploads a file, if I run it directly. but it fails in save_model.
obj.file.path returns an MEDIA_PATH + filename and it looks like file is missing on moment of of save_model executing.

How should I copy file the right way?

ps. It looks like there is FileUploadHandler.upload_complete(), but I'm not sure if (and how) I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to save file in save_model I just have to call form.save() function in it. Like this:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        form.save()
        obj.answer = remote_upload(obj.file.path)
        obj.save()
```

So easy =)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify where you want to copy to by setting the upload_to as a function. This can be done in the Model itself.

[How to use upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Example:

```
def upload_to_special_path(instance, filename):
    return #The path that you want to have.

class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_special_path)
```

Comment: unfortunately that's not my case, as upload_to can't upload the file to the remote server. and I need two copies: on local and remote sides.

Comment: What i mean is can you update the file to the remote path and also return the local path in the upload_to_special_path function?

Comment: No, unfortunately the remote server randomly generates a file path on upload and I can't predict it. So I have to upload it first and only after that I'll get a value to save. Also remote server is not under my control and I can change nothing there.